# How to assign custom colors to jqwidget chart columns?

Tags: angular, jqwidget

I am trying to set a custom color to each and every column of the chart, I found the series option but it was setting the color to the series. I want to set the color to each and every column.

Here is angular code for more details.

`

```
colorScheme = {
        domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
    };

    //////////////////////////

        sampleData: any = [];

        padding: any = { left: 20, top: 5, right: 20, bottom: 5 };

        titlePadding: any = { left: 90, top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 10 };

        xAxis: any =
        {
            dataField: 'name',
            gridLines: { visible: true },
            flip: false
        };

        valueAxis: any =
        {
            flip: true,
            labels: {
                    visible: true,
                    formatFunction: (value: string) => {
                        return parseInt(value, 10) / 1000000;
                }
            }
        };

        seriesGroups: any[] =
        [
            {
                type: 'column',
                columnsGapPercent: 50,
                seriesGapPercent: 0,
                valueAxis:
                {
                    unitInterval: 100000,
                    minValue: 0,
                    maxValue: 1000000,
                    displayValueAxis: true,
                    description: 'Amount  (in lakhs)',
                    axisSize: 'auto',
                    tickMarksColor: '#888888',
                    formatFunction: (value: string) => {
                        return parseInt(value, 10) / 100000 || 5;
                    }
                },
                series: [
                    { dataField: 'value', displayText: 'Amount' }
                ]
            }
        ];
```

`

Comment: Please show what you have tried, and share the code

Comment: I have added the code.